# How to resize a div on window resize?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I want to display a list of items together with their description in 4 columns, but when I resize the windows I want that only 2 columns are displayed, meaning the item together with its description, but what is actually happening is that when I resize the window the items columns together with their description column are one on the other and it becomes unreadable.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">                
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                       Item nr.1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                       Description
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                        Item nr.2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                        Description
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>                      
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                       Item nr.3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                       Description
                    </div>
                </div>                      
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                        Item nr.4
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                        Description
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>          
</div>
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to change the above html such that when the window is resized the 4 columns become 2?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use again and again "row" inside the row, if their is need then use.
also follow the bootstrap stander don't add your own thing you will break the strct

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    Item nr.1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    Description
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    Item nr.2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    Description
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    Item nr.1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    Description
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    Item nr.2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    Description
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Item nr.1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Description
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Item nr.2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Description
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Item nr.3
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Description
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Item nr.4
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    Description
  </div>
</div>
```

demo : http://codepen.io/hmache/pen/yJzyox
take a look at bootstrap's grid documentation : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options